# Custom Controls on Gridview

Tags: data-binding, gridview, repeater

How Do I Bind my datasource to a custom control on a GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:DVDBox ID="DVDBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:DVDBox ID="DVDBox2" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:DVDBox ID="DVDBox3" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to bind it with the usual

```
        GridView1.DataSource = Results;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

But its not working!

Will I have to address each element of each of each of the occurrences of the custom control to get the data to render or am I missing something?.

Comment: i did suggest you go one question at a time.

Comment: Yer, I know your right, I have been having a bad day sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

OK I had to answer this for myself.

So just for future reference.

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:DVDBox ID="DVDBox1" runat="server" 
                    controlNameInCustomControl='<%# Bind("NameOfColumnOnSource") %>'
                    />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now I just need to work out to repeat this for several GridView Columns with the same custom control